# Php mhash function

Tags: php

I have recently registered an application with windows Live. After receiving my secret # and api # I downloaded the PHP code samples and updated the XML files to include the api and secret IDs. When I run sample #1, it takes me to the login page for windows live, and then I get this:

www.abcxyz.com is making an insecure request to access your information. Windows Live does not allow information to be shared with this type of request.

After trying to get this to work for a while, I decided to post the problem on this forum.

One more thing, Our domain does not have the function mhash installed, but we have all the other hash functions (that are emulated by mhash according to php.net) installed. mhash is being invoked exactly once in windowslivelogin.php so I replaced with with standard hash. I am not sure if this could be causing the problem or not but it is worth noting.

Any help will be greatly appreciated since this is halting development. Thank you!!!!

And if i could use an alias please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The mhash extension implements many other hashes than PHP itself does, and allows more fine-grained tweaking of the output.  I'd advise asking to persuade your hosting company to add the mhash extension to PHP, and if they refuse, finding another hosting provider that does provide mhash or are willing to install it.